# When building my flutter app, it fails with GradleExeption

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, build.gradle

When I try to build my app for public release I get this error from the app level `build.gradle`. I'm getting the error below:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G973F in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\AndroidStudioProjects\tab_truth_true\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\AndroidStudioProjects\tab_truth_true\android\app\build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\AndroidStudioProjects\tab_truth_true\android\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\AndroidStudioProjects\tab_truth_true\android\app\build.gradle': 11: unable to resolve class GradleExeption 
   @ line 11, column 11.
         throw new GradleExeption("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
               ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\AndroidStudioProjects\tab_truth_true\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

This is the app level `build.gradle` code:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleExeption("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1.0.0'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.tab.tab_truth_true"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

I have tried everything, what I know, but achieved nothing.  please help me out.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I hope this is right, but Android Studio. This error is fixed, it was a typo but thank you anyways.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct answer so people can see that help isn't needed anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo in your Gradle file, change `GradleExeption` to `GradleException` at line 11 in your Gradle file.